# rails can you reference a model within a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to have run into a problem with trying to use a model in another model in Rails.

I am pulling a list of users from Active Directory with LDAP in a dropdown.  I want to parse the cn that I get from Ldap into a firstname and lastname.

The problem I am running into is that I need to find a record in the users model. The parsing is being done in observations.rb.

Observation.rb:

```
    def parse_employee

    @emp_name = ''  #initialize
    self.employee_raw = self.employee_raw[2...-2] # get rid of the quotes and brackets
    @emp_name = self.employee_raw.split(' ') # split first/last names
    @emp_first_name = @emp_name[0] #Grab the first name
    @emp_last_name = @emp_name[1]  # grab the surname


    @user = User.where("last_name like ?", @emp_last_name)

    self.employee_id = @user.id

  end
```

I've played with this quite a bit and it appears that I can't reference other models from within a model.

To sum up, what I am trying to do is
1. Have the user select the appropriate person from a dropdown that is pulled via LDAP from active directory. 
2. Use the first and last names to find the appropriate user in my user table (Right now I'm just trying to get it to work with the last name as that is unique enough)
3. When I find the correct user in the user table, enter that id in the employee_id field in my observations table.

Comment: Yes you can reference a model in any other model so calling the User class in your Observation class is completely valid.

Comment: Is this when dealing with a specific form in your application or will there be a User with every observation creation?

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thanks- Given that you said you could call a model in a model, I fiddled with the code a bit more and got that part working.

Comment: Excellent.  If this is just for one part of your application (like dealing with a form on one page) let me know and I'll show you how to build what is known as a Form Model.  It's a bit more work up front but makes maintenance and further dev. super easy since you won't have a ton of methods jammed into your Observation.rb file.

Comment: Chris, note that the `where` query method does not return a User but a query builder object, a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You need to use a method that actually returns model instances. You could try `User.where(...).first` or `User.find_by(...)` (or `User.find_by!(...)` depending on the use case). Also see the Rails Guide on querying: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html